# How can I retrieve & display Outlook/Exchange Calendar events in my web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, outlook, exchange-server

I'm building a web application (built in html/JavaScript/jQuery) that has a built-in calendar. I would like to pull in my Outlook/Exchange Calendar events and display them in my web application's calendar. What is the best way to do that from a JavaScript/jQuery environment? I've been searching all over for plugins or examples of how to talk to Exchange/Outlook and retrieve events but I haven't found a solution yet. We are currently using MS Office/Outlook 2010 and I'm not sure what the Exchange version is but can find out if that's relevant. I don't need to modify the calendar events, just read them. (Note that I can't just use an OWA Web Parts link such as "https://webmail.mycompany.com/owa/?cmd=contents&module=calendar&view=monthly" to display the calendar in an iframe; I need to have access to the actual event data so I can include other UI elements that I need for my application.)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a combination of OAuth and the outlook API.  I doubt it will be easy but here are some starting points...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the "Outlook.com API" (first link) is relevant when using Outlook with an Exchange Server, is it? From what I have been reading it seems that Outlook.com is an entirely different entity than Outlook/Exchange.

Comment: do you have your own exchange server set up?

Comment: Yes, we are using an exchange server.

Comment: The exchange server is relevant because there are REST api's set up to use that.  Also you should do it with just javascript on the front end, unless it is for only your use.  Otherwise people will have access to all of your information.